# Add a Carousel Slideshow gallery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, carousel

I'm learning HTML, CSS and Java.
I'm tryng to add to my website a slideshow but i don't understand why i don't see nothing when i try to run it. I found this one and i'm try to make it work but i can't see an image, i can see only the pointer to go next or back.

```
    <!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container">

    <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 9</div>
      <img src="FotoGP.jpg" style="width:100%">
      
    </div>
  
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 9</div>
      <img src="FotoSalaPesi.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Sala Pesi</div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 9</div>
      <img src="FotoSalaCardio.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Cardio</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">4 / 9</div>
        <img src="FotoSalaCircuiti.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Circuiti Funzionali</div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">5 / 9</div>
        <img src="FotoSalaAddominali.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">6 / 9</div>
        <img src="FotoSalaGambe.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">7 / 9</div>
        <img src="FotoSalaBilanceri.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Sala Pesi</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">8 / 9</div>
        <img src="FotoAperto.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">All'aperto</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">9 / 9</div>
        <img src="FotoUfficio.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>


    <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <br>
  
  <!-- The dots/circles -->
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(6)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(7)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(8)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(9)"></span>
  </div>
```

This is CSS part

```
    * {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

And JS

```
    var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}


var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

what i'm missing? Thank you for your help!

Comment: nothing's wrong with your codes just check the path of your images

Answer (score 0):

The path of your image seems not right

Look it works with placeholders

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}


var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Hide the images by default */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 9</div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="width:100%">

  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 9</div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Sala Pesi</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 9</div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Cardio</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 9</div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Circuiti Funzionali</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">5 / 9</div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">6 / 9</div>
    <img src="FotoSalaGambe.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">7 / 9</div>
    <img src="FotoSalaBilanceri.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Sala Pesi</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">8 / 9</div>
    <img src="FotoAperto.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">All'aperto</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">9 / 9</div>
    <img src="FotoUfficio.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>


  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(6)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(7)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(8)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(9)"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You're right i made some mistake! Thank you so much for answer me!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how new you are to HTML but here are some common fixes:

- Make sure to double-check your image sources are correct. And if you they are in a another directory, include the relative path to the image. Ex.: `<img src="images/FotoAperto.jpg">`
- Make sure you have your css imports right. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`
- Check if your JS script is imported right, and place the `<script>` tag after the closing`</body>`-tag `<script src="index.js"></script>`.

I hope it helped :)

Comment: Yeah my JS script wasn't imported in right way. Thank you so much! 
If i can, i will ask you another question. Now slideshow works, but i cannot set the time like i want. Default is like 1 sec and it's ok the photo switch, if i set like 5 sec when i run code i can see for 1 sec the photo and for 4 sec white screen, and after switch to next pic. How can i solve?

Comment: Glad I could help! Feel free to mark my answer as a accepted solution. :)

Regarding your next question, I tried changing the `setTimeout(showSlides, 5000);` to 5000 and this works for me as intended. The slides & images are changing every 5 seconds.